# What is the meaning of '@' sign in cshtml?

Tags: c#, .net, html

Could you explain me what is meant by '@' sign before each variable in cshtml?

Comment: "The @ character starts inline expressions, single statement blocks, and multi-statement blocks:" - from http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/basics/2-introduction-to-asp-net-web-programming-using-the-razor-syntax If you are unfamiliar with cshtml/Razor, start here!

Comment: -1 because there can be variables w/o `@` and `@` w/o variables. You could at least have includes a few sample lines.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

@ is used to switch from view markup to code. Whether to print a single value or to write a code block.

From [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/basics/2-introduction-to-asp-net-web-programming-using-the-razor-syntax):

> The @ character starts inline expressions, single statement blocks,
>   and multi-statement blocks:

Read a [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/razor_intro.asp) on its syntax

Comment: Your tutorial link is dead.

Answer (score 4):

I'll try to simplify the answer. I myself wrote a piece of code and figured it out.The most frequently used places are:-

- Used to place comments in a Razor view (@* This is a commented line *@)
- When used with ViewData or Viewbag attributes being returned directly from the controller.( ex. `@ViewData["SomeVariable"]` )
- Used to mark a section of server side code in the razor view.It could
  be a one-liner or even a block. (ex.  `@{int flag = 0, lastVar = 0;}`  )
- Used to depict a inline variable coming from a model(as in MVC) which
  is used along with standard html tags. (ex.  `<i>You reached a new level <b> @item.levelName  </b></i>`   )

**NOTE:** This '@' symbol for inline variable must be placed EVEN if the expression is already inside a block of server code already depicted with the '@' symbol.

```
  <ul>
    @for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    <li>@i</li>     /*See this inline depiction despite the external for-loop already depicted.*/
    }
    </ul>
```